# Services > YouTube Data API v3 > youtube.search.list parameter type not filtering for videos

Tags: youtube-data-api

I was trying to get a list that excluded playlists and channels.

The documentation says that setting parameter type=video will do that.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

However, the parameter seems to have no effect, I still get a playlist as the top result.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=3&q=Demi+Lovato+Sorry+Not+Sorry&type=video&videoSyndicated=any&_h=2&

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=3&q=Demi+Lovato+Sorry+Not+Sorry&type=video&videoSyndicated=any&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Me, also tried this query and seems it's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, maybe am old bug?
my function

```
 fetchVideos(query: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=${query}
        &type=video
        &key=KEY`)
      .pipe(
        map(response => console.log(response) )
      );
  }
```

Comment: Does it filter out playlists for you?

Comment: it returns me the list of videos. What you mean by fitler out? it's just a request and response.

Comment: If you use the same query as I did here:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=3&q=Demi+Lovato+Sorry+Not+Sorry&type=video&videoSyndicated=any&_h=2&


The first entry in the response is a playlist which shouldn't be there because we added query parameter type=video in our URL. We should only have videos in the response list.

"id": {
    "kind": "youtube#playlist",
    "playlistId": "PLJ49NV73ttrutlLqBBYmYyvPxzRft9q4s"
   }